# Fetching the total amount of SE reputation accumulated

Tags: r, stackexchange

Since I am new to R, I have pulled this code together in kind of a rag-tag way, but I am wondering, is there something similar to list comprehensions (in Python) I can use in R to make this simpler? Or a better way of doing this? I am trying to fetch the total amount of reputation a user has accumulated on Stack Exchange.  I am ideally looking for a way to remove the `for` loop and use the `sum` function on a subset of items (from the API response).

```
library(httr)
s = 0
for(i in content(GET(paste("http://api.stackexchange.com/users/",readline(),"/associated",sep="")))$items) {
  q=i$reputation
  if (q>101) 
    s=s+q
}
print(s)
```

Sample input would be a user's id, like `10400443`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R does not offer list comprehensions like Python, but a similar thing called the [apply](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-on-the-apply-family-of-functions/) family of functions. In addition, there is packages called [purrr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/index.html) that offers similar functionality with a more user-friendly interface. Below is an example how to compute the sum using these tools.

```
library('httr')
user_url <- paste0("http://api.stackexchange.com/users/", readline(), "/associated")
dat <- content(GET(user_url))$items

sum(vapply(dat, function(x) ifelse(x$reputation > 101, x$reputation, 0), 1))

library('purrr')
sum(map_dbl(dat, ~ifelse(.x$reputation > 101, .x$reputation, 0)))
```

Answer (score 4):

It's simple to extract all reputation and subsequently sum an index. This is instead of performing the ifelse inside the *apply function to demonstrate indexing.

```
library(httr)
allc <- content(GET(paste0("http://api.stackexchange.com/users/",'10400443',"/associated")))
allci <- allc$items

# get all reputation out of list
allrep <- sapply(allci,`[[`,'reputation')

# sum only index of > 101
sum(allrep[allrep > 101])
```

I'm not familiar with Python, but it appears that indexing in R serves the same purpose as list comprehension in Python - [list comprehension in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998716/list-comprehension-in-r)